# How Do I Make Sure Only One JRadioButton Is Selected In Java?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I have three `JRadioButton`s added to a `JPanel`. However, when I select one, I can select another one and the previous one selected stays selected. How can I make sure that only one is selected at a time?

My `JPanel` class, which is added by my main `JFrame`:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private static JRadioButton addHouse, addRoad, calculateDist;

    static {
        addHouse = new JRadioButton("Add House");
        addRoad = new JRadioButton("Add Road");
        calculateDist = new JRadioButton("Calculate Distance");
    }

    MainPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        addHouse.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
        addRoad.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 50);
        addHouse.setBounds(50, 250, 100, 50);

        addHouse.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addRoad.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        calculateDist.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(addHouse);
        add(addRoad);
        add(calculateDist);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't share the complete code i can't tell how to do it in your case but in general

**It can be done like that**

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup() // create a button group , buttons in a button group knows how to behave together 
JRadioButton radioButton1 = new JRadioButton("R1"); // create your buttons 
JRadioButton radioButton2 = new JRadioButton("R2"); // as many you want

buttonGroup.add(radioButton1); // make them part of group
buttonGroup.add(radioButton2);
myJFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // or any layout you want
myJFrame.add(radioButton1);    // add buttons to jframe 
myJFrame.add(radioButton1);
```

when buttons were added to JFrame (or any other container) they were part of a group , so group handles the communications between them, now you can check only one at a time,
try commenting buttonGroup.add(); you will loose that behaveiour .

Same thing can be achieved manually , it that case you will track all other radio buttons 
at every selection to check if others are already check and then uncheck them which is tedious so better use ButtonGroup class of swing

Comment: Thanks! I just have two questions: 1. Can you use a null layout? I know it's good practice to use a layout but just in case in the future I need a null layout. 2. Can I add my buttons which are part of a button group to a JPanel?

Comment: Sure you can add buttons anywhere , and you can also use null layout, using null layout means you're using absolute positioning , so you have give your button locations which is not recommended , because then buttons will stick to that position even if the container is resized , will also misbehave of different screens, also learn more about button group at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `JRadioButton`s in a `ButtonGroup` instance first. Here is a simple example:

```
// configure buttons bounds, background etc.

ButtonGroup buttonGroup= new ButtonGroup();
buttonGroup.add(addHouse);
buttonGroup.add(addRoad);
buttonGroup.add(calculateDist);

// add the buttons to the panel too.
```